# Portable way to read symlink destination in shell

Tags: shell, sh, ls, stat

Is there a way to portably (at least Linux and macOS) get the destination of a symlink in a (Posix) shell script?
In [an old program](https://github.com/iraf-community/iraf/blob/c2e107fc404aa26d135741357882d19744512815/unix/hlib/irafarch.sh#L83-L85), I found

```bash
ls -lad "bin" 2> /dev/null | awk '{ printf ("%s\n", $11) }'
```

which however fails when user name or group name contains spaces.

**stat(1)** (which IMO would be the canonical solution) has different options on [Linux](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages-en/stat.1.de.html) and [macOS](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/stat/).

Comment: See [BashFAQ #29](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/029), and particularly the perl solution therein; perl isn't POSIX-specified, but it _is_ pretty much ubiquitous.

Comment: Mind, Linux and MacOS is not very aggressive as a platform-support target; if those are the only platforms you care about there's `readlink` or `realpath`.